# Can Visual Studio 2017 be installed and used on Windows 10 on ARM (i.e. Asus NovaGo)?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, arm

I am struggling to find information on this. Of course certain features such as docker and hyper-v will not function, but will Visual Studio 2017 be able to be installed and run on a Windows 10 always-connected ARM device? Like, would typical desktop/web development scenarios with .NET/C++/Python work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible**. I just got a Asus Nova Go and tried it. Compiling and running a basic .net Core app (with an Avalonia UI) worked just fine but there are some limitations and corner cases that hopefully will get fixed.

Visual Studio takes long to launch, and when lauched is not very performant.

I think the Lenovo Yoga C630 is snappier, because of the bigger 8GB RAM and the Snapdragon 850.

If you have any further questions let me know

Comment: Hey @JaggerJo, I actually just got one myself - and to my surprise it worked! Definitely sluggish as you say, but it is workable for lightweight activities. I actually found that Eclipse worked surprisingly well too.